# Unexpected working of new attribute of Session class in Flask

Tags: python, session, flask

According to the [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.session.new) documentation, `new` attribute returns `True` if the session is new. otherwise `False`, but in my case, it always returns `False` no matter what. Here is the code:

```
@app.route('/set-session/')
def testing_session():
    session['user_id'] = 'jon'
    print(session.new)    # always returns True . Why ?
    print(session.modified)
    return 'playing with session'
```

Comment: It looks like bug. [JFYI](https://github.com/pallets/flask/issues/2564)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [code](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/a43a439c7a839edc8c5ac7062acb694eceb99e55/flask/sessions.py#L37-L40):

```
#: some session backends can tell you if a session is new, but that is
#: not necessarily guaranteed.  Use with caution.  The default mixin
#: implementation just hardcodes ``False`` in.
new = False
```

The default session does not try to track whether a session is new.

See [this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/pallets/flask/issues/2564)